# I want To implement sharing NFC Tag without opening App like passing from airport with passport

Tags: android, ios, flutter, nfc, flutter-platform-channel

I want to implement an App to make user able to share specific data to a reader device without opening my App like applepay, googlepay airport passing passport

Answer (score 1):

If the reader is only a true reading device and the only thing it expects to do is to read a NFC Tag (or a device pretending to be an NFC Tag, as in the case of your applepay, googlepay example).

Then on iOS what you want to do is not possible by you, Apple only allow themselves to do this.

On Android which has better NFC support it is possible to write a Host Card Emulation service that will run in the background that will pretend to be a NFC Tag. see the docs https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce

Comment: Thanks, @Andrew for the info but if I want to make an action to write on IOS is that possible?

Comment: It is possible for an iOS device to be an "initiator" in NFC communication terms and write Data from a running App to a "target" device in NFC communication terms (most usually a Tag or something pretending to be a Tag). But most reading hardware won't be in "target" device mode if it is capable of doing that, it will be expecting to initiate the communication. If you control the reading hardware and it has the necessary capabilities then you could make it work for an iOS App to send data to another NFC device.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest reading Apple's docs on "Core NFC", the library that implements NFC in iOS.

I don't think you can do what you are asking to do. (You can't transmit an RFC tag while your app is suspended/quit or the phone is locked.)

A quick glance at those docs says that you can add support for background tag reading, and then have the "reader" start out by transmitting as an NFC tag. That would let you display a notification. Once the user taps the notification your app could be launched and notified. See the section titled "Adding Support for Background Tag Reading."

Comment: To Share data with a "reader" device from a phone when you have suggested that you changed the "reader" in to a device that does Card emulation (inverting the normal relationship) then the phone would have to do background "writing" of data to send the data from phone to the "reader" and I don't think iOS supports background NFC writing

Comment: That's the point. I also don't think iOS supports background writing. If you had a reader that was sending, you could have the iOS device in background reading mode at all time. When it detected the reader/writer, it could display a notification to the user, who could then tap to bring your app to the foreground and transmit. I think that's the best you're going to be able to do given Apple's restrictions on 3rd party apps.

Comment: Yes true IF you can change the other "reader" device to become a "Tag" to send data that would cause your background reading method to launch a foreground App to send data back by writing to what it believes is a Tag. There are just 2 problems it's not in the background as requested and the other "reader" device won't normally be in the required mode of operation to do this.